error in golang websocket client trying to connect nestjs gateway
I am working on build a go client for nestjs gateway websocket server.
When i connect to the gateway using postman it connect fine,
but when i try to connect using gorilla/websocket always stuck and not connected  and shows many errors like:
2024/06/27 23:33:48 Error connecting to WebSocket: unexpected EOF

Here is the code:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "time"

    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

func main() {
    url := "ws://localhost:3000" //

    c, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error connecting to WebSocket: %v", err)
    }
    defer c.Close()

    go func() {
        defer c.Close()
        for {
            _, msg, err := c.ReadMessage()
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("Error reading from WebSocket: %v", err)
                return
            }
            fmt.Printf("Received message: %s\n", msg)
        }
    }()

    ticker := time.NewTicker(5 * time.Second)
    defer ticker.Stop()

    done := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(done, os.Interrupt)

    for {
        select {
        case <-done:
            fmt.Println("Exiting...")
            return
        case <-ticker.C:
            message := []byte("Hello from Go!")
            err := c.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, message)
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("Error sending message over WebSocket: %v", err)
                return
            }
            fmt.Printf("Sent message: %s\n", message)
        }
    }
}


import {
  SubscribeMessage,
  WebSocketGateway,
  WebSocketServer,
  OnGatewayInit,
  OnGatewayConnection,
  OnGatewayDisconnect,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Server, WebSocket } from 'ws';

@WebSocketGateway()
export class SockServerGateway
  implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect
{
  @WebSocketServer() server: Server;
  private clients: Map<string, WebSocket > = new Map();

  afterInit(server: Server) {
    console.log('WebSocket server initialized');
  }


  handleConnection(client: WebSocket ) {
    this.clients.set(client.id, client);
    console.log(`Client connected: ${client.id}`);
    this.displayClients();
  }

  handleDisconnect(client: WebSocket ) {
    this.clients.delete(client.id);
    console.log(`Client disconnected: ${client.id}`);
    this.displayClients();
  }

  @SubscribeMessage('message')
  handleMessage(client: WebSocket , payload: string): void {
    console.log(`Received message from ${client.id}: ${payload}`);
    // Broadcast the message to all clients
    client.emit("message","xxx")
    this.server.emit('message', `Message from ${client.id}: ${payload}`);
  }

  private displayClients() {
    console.log('Connected clients:');
    this.clients.forEach((_, id) => {
      console.log(id);
    });
  }

  // Method to send a message to a specific client
  sendMessageToClient(clientId: string, message: string): void {
    const client = this.clients.get(clientId);
    if (client) {
      client.emit('message', message);
    } else {
      console.log(`Client with ID ${clientId} not found`);
    }
  }

  // Method to send a message to all clients
  sendMessageToAllClients(message: string): void {
    this.server.emit('message', message);
  }
}


I try to connect to my nestjs gateway server using go websocket but always fail. I need example of golang client that works with nestjs gateway

I believe nestjs @WebSocketGateway() uses a Socket.IO adapter by default (gorilla will not connect to a Socket.IO server) , which did you use when testing in Postman?
